# Python: How to graph $y^2=x^3-7+3$?

Tags: python, graph

Python: How to graph $y^2=x^3-7+3$?

I have been searching online but I can't find a way to do it.

Comment: You should consider exploring the python library MatPlotLib

Comment: You're saying you googled 'how to graph in python' and found nothing? [First link](http://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html)

Comment: `x^3-7+3` is the same as `x^3-4`. Did you mean `x^3-7x+3` perhaps?

Answer (score 3):

[Matplotlib's `contour` function](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.contour) can be used to plot the solution to implicit equations:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

y, x = np.ogrid[-4:4:1000j, -6:6:1000j]
plt.contour(
    x.ravel(), y.ravel(), y**2 - x**3 + 7*x -3, [0])
plt.show()
```

yields

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With `matplotlib` and `numpy`:

```
import matplolib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from math import sqrt

x = np.arange(10,100) # You have to choose the domain you are looking to plot
y = [sqrt(i**3 - 7 + 3) for i in x]

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Well, actually you have to be careful with the domain of the function, in order to choose `+sqrt` or `-sqrt`.